# convert a LongBuffer/IntBuffer/ShortBuffer to ByteBuffer

Tags: java, arrays, nio

I know a quick way to convert a byte/short/int/long array to ByteBuffer, and then obtain a byte array. For instance, to convert a byte array to short array I can do:

```
byte[] bArray = { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(byteArray);
ShortBuffer sb = bb.asShortBuffer();
short[] shortArray = new short[byteArray.length / 2];
sb.get(shortArray);
```

produces a short array like this: `[256, 0, 0, 0, 256, 0, 0, 0]`.

**How can I do the inverse operation using [java.nio](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/package-summary.html) classes?**

Now I am doing this:

```
shortArray[] = {256, 0, 0, 0, 256, 0, 0, 0};
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(shortArray.length * 2);
for (short s : shortArray) {
    bb.putShort(s);
}
return bb.array();
```

And I obtain the original `[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]` byte array. But  I want to use a method like ShortBuffer.asByteBuffer(), not a manual loop to do it.

I have found a [request to Sun of 2001](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4489356), but they did not accept it ;-((

Comment: It's worth pointing out that in your link Oracle says that without backing of a _direct_ ByteBuffer, providing such a 'view' would still require a copy operation when writing I/O. That is their reason for not providing this method.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

What about this? :

```
    bb.asShortBuffer().put(shortArray);
```

Then `bb` contains your data.

**Full code**:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(final String args[]) {
        short[] arr = { 256, 0, 0, 0, 256, 0, 0, 0 };
        for (byte b : F(arr)) {
            System.out.print(b);
        }
    }

    public static byte[] F(short[] arr) {
        java.nio.ByteBuffer bb = java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(arr.length * 2);
        bb.asShortBuffer().put(arr);
        return bb.array(); // this returns the "raw" array, it's shared and not copied!
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, this is so clever!

Comment: ByteBuffer.allocate(arr.length * 2) is going to allocate length*2 bytes so this method is copying the data rather than casting a short[] to a byte[]

Comment: @morpheus The Q was about "conversion" not "casting".

Comment: is it possible to "cast" in java i.e., convert short[] to byte[] without additional memory allocation?

Comment: @morpheus None I'm aware of. `Buffer` is the only mechanism where you can get a `byte` or `short` view on the same data. But plain arrays are not castable the way you want.

Answer (score 3):

Well, in the declaration

```
ShortBuffer sb = bb.asShortBuffer();
```

AFAIK, your `ShortBuffer` is just a view of the original `ByteBuffer`. So, you could always access the original `ByteBuffer` variable `bb` and see the data as modified through your `CharBuffer` reference `sb`.

The documentation for [asCharBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#asCharBuffer%28%29) says:

> [...] Changes to this buffer's content will be visible in the new
>   buffer, and vice versa [...]

Comment: @logoff How about `ByteBuffer.wrap(sb.toString().getBytes())`?

Comment: it does not work. the result is `[106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 110, 105, 111, 46, 72, 101, 97, 112, 83, 104, 111, 114, 116, 66, 117, 102, 102, 101, 114, 91, 112, 111, 115, 61, 48, 32, 108, 105, 109, 61, 56, 32, 99, 97, 112, 61, 56, 93]`. it is because `sb.toString()` return `java.nio.HeapShortBuffer[pos=0 lim=8 cap=8]`

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo, Man even if that *does* work, `sb.toString().getBytes()` is extremely ugly if we are hacking `toString` like this...

Answer (score 0):

I would remember the ByteBuffer you used to create the ShortBuffer from as its a view onto the same buffer.

Otherwise it appears the only way to get this back is to use reflections to get the `bb` field.

BTW: Using a direct ByteBuffer can be significantly faster depending on what you are doing esp if you use native byte order.

Comment: Using a direct ByteBuffer is faster, but I cannot access the backing array later.

Comment: What do you use the backing array for?

Comment: not in my snippet, but I finally need it. anyway your comment is correct, but I need the array, hehe.

Comment: My point is that often you need it for something like writing to a file or a socket. If you use NIO you can avoid turning it into a byte array.

Comment: yes, it is true. I am doing some "strange things", only concept proof of concept. thank you anyway