# Java How to convert a java.nio.Buffer into a ByteBuffer

Tags: java

I'm facing a little problem I have two libraries one send me the output as java.nio.Buffer and the other receives the input as a java.nio.ByteBuffer how do I make the conversion?

Thanks

the Buffer is from javaCV from this piece of code:

```
private BytePointer[]   image_ptr;
private Buffer[]        image_buf;

// Determine required buffer size and allocate buffer
int size = avpicture_get_size(fmt, width, height);
image_ptr = new BytePointer[] { new BytePointer(av_malloc(size)).capacity(size) };
image_buf = new Buffer[] { image_ptr[0].asBuffer() };

// Assign appropriate parts of buffer to image planes in picture_rgb
// Note that picture_rgb is an AVFrame, but AVFrame is a superset of AVPicture
avpicture_fill(new AVPicture(picture_rgb), image_ptr[0], fmt, width, height);
picture_rgb.format(fmt);
picture_rgb.width(width);
picture_rgb.height(height);
```

Comment: Well, `java.nio.Buffer` is an abstract class. What's the actual type of the result? Does it vary? What does it contain?

Comment: I suppose the problem is if the actual type of the buffer is not in fact ByteBuffer. If `b instanceof ByteBuffer` is true then a casting should suffice, otherwise things get a bit more complicated.

Comment: added the Buffer context, the buffer[] has only 1 element, Buffer.hasArray returns false a direct conversion betwenn Buffer and ByteBuffer throws an UnsoportedOperation

Comment: @RoyBean If your `Buffer`is not backed by an array (i.e. `hasArray` is false) then you cannot safely invoke `array()` and `arrayOffset()`. I suppose one of those is the one causing the unsupported operation exception, right?

Comment: See the linked question - you can allocate a new `ByteBuffer` and call `asXxxBuffer().put(...)` to populate it, depending on the actual type of your `Buffer` (so you'll need to test them all).

Comment: Argh, seriously? I was about to post an answer when this was closed. There goes 30 minutes of writing.

Comment: @Tunaki I am not sure the suggested answer addresses this question. The suggested answer seems to imply the Buffer is backed by an array, which I don't think it is necessarily the case. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Edward No, this is not wasted time! You can post it on the linked question, which are the same: convert an instance of `Buffer` to `ByteBuffer`. The answers there could be improved indeed.

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo No, the answers could be better... But since the questions are really the same, it is better to centralize that in a single place.

Comment: @Tunaki I think this question has been prematurely closed. I don't think I could derive an answer for this from the suggested duplicate. The allegedly duplicate answer would have been a good reference, but unless somebody goes there and addresses this case too, then this question is still unanswered in my opinion. The actual `Buffer` in the question may not be backed by an array and may be of any other type deriving `Buffer` not only those from the JDK.

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo The questions are exactly the same. This is the best opportunity to update the linked question with other answers. The goal is not to have information at multiple places. There is one question that addresses this topic, so it should cover it completely. This way, it enhances the value of the question and makes it even more of a canonical.

Comment: Roy, you haven't answered the question. What is the actual type of the `Buffer`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, since Buffer is an abstract class, and ByteBuffer is one of its subclasses, it's entirely possible that the output you're getting from the first library is in fact a ByteBuffer. If possible, check to see which implementation of Buffer the library is returning, because if it's actually returning a ByteBuffer you can just cast the output to ByteBuffer and be done.

If you don't know which implementation of Buffer the library returns, you'll have to resort to `instanceof` tests to determine what subclass it is, and copy the data from the returned Buffer to a new ByteBuffer after downcasting it to a subclass. This is because the Buffer interface doesn't  actually provide any methods to read the data from the buffer; only the subclasses (ByteBuffer, ShortBuffer, LongBuffer, etc.) do. Fortunately, there are only 7 possible subclasses of Buffer, one for each primitive type.

Once you've determined which subclass of Buffer you have, you can copy the data to a ByteBuffer using the "asXXXBuffer()" method described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11665147/convert-a-longbuffer-intbuffer-shortbuffer-to-bytebuffer), as @Tunaki pointed out.

The code would look something like this:

```
Buffer outputBuffer = library.getBuffer();
ByteBuffer byteBuffer;
if (outputBuffer instanceof ByteBuffer) {
    byteBuffer = (ByteBuffer) outputBuffer;
} else if (outputBuffer instanceof CharBuffer) {
    byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(outputBuffer.capacity());
    byteBuffer.asCharBuffer().put((CharBuffer) outputBuffer);
} else if (outputBuffer instanceof ShortBuffer) {
    byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(outputBuffer.capacity() * 2);
    byteBuffer.asShortBuffer().put((ShortBuffer) outputBuffer);
} else if (outputBuffer instanceof IntBuffer) {
    byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(outputBuffer.capacity() * 4);
    byteBuffer.asIntBuffer().put((IntBuffer) outputBuffer);
} else if (outputBuffer instanceof LongBuffer) {
    byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(outputBuffer.capacity() * 8);
    byteBuffer.asLongBuffer().put((LongBuffer) outputBuffer);
} else if (outputBuffer instanceof FloatBuffer) {
    byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(outputBuffer.capacity() * 4);
    byteBuffer.asFloatBuffer().put((FloatBuffer) outputBuffer);
} else if (outputBuffer instanceof DoubleBuffer) {
    byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(outputBuffer.capacity() * 8);
    byteBuffer.asDoubleBuffer().put((DoubleBuffer) outputBuffer);
}
```

Note that the size of the ByteBuffer you allocate depends on which subclass of Buffer you're copying from, since different primitive types are stored using different numbers of bytes. For example, since an int is 4 bytes, if your library gives you an IntBuffer, you need to allocate a ByteBuffer with 4 times the capacity.